# Editing question does not add an extra +2

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have several accounts on the SE subsites. When editing a question on a subsite where I have a low reputation and someone has to approve my edits, I get +2 bonus once the edits are approved. However, on SO where I do not need approval and can make a direct edit, I do not get a +2 bonus. Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Definitely by design. If not, I can go on an edit spree just to gain rep.

Comment: It would be great if someone could please explain the down votes, so I can ask the question a bit better next time or refrain from asking a question that people find worth marking negatively so heavily.

Comment: It wasn't because you didn't put enough effort in asking a question. [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). People simply disagree with your idea.

Comment: @Antony: Thanks but that doesn't really help

Comment: @Antony: Well, actually, it probably is from lack of research. This is all explained in the FAQ on every site: *"The other way to gain reputation is by suggesting edits to existing posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however."*

Comment: @animuson: thanks, that helps

Comment: @animuson I was confused by the wording of that until I found this question. Nothing in that section from the FAQ tipped me off that once I get the reputation to revise freely, I'd no longer get rep. Makes sense, but wasn't immediately obvious. I might just be dumb though ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[You have more than 2000 reputation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575171/divi).  You have already earned the right to [edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) without having them be reviewed.  You do not earn points for editing after that.  You can only earn points if you have less than 2000 reputation, you haven't already earned more than 1000 reputation from edit suggestions total and you suggest an edit that gets approved.

That is how it is by design.

Comment: It was a while ago, but I still remember the great feeling you get when you earn a `+2`